# All QT applications on my windows machine have garbled GUI

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

Starting recently, all QT applications have problems with window sizing and offset, f.i. the window origin (0,0) seems to be moved left and up, so that the menu disappears.

This is how it should look:
[image]

And this is how it looks with the problem:
[image]

Any idea what setting might have gone haywire ?

Comment: Check your PATH and other library environment variables and make sure you're not using the wrong shared library version of Qt in these programs. Qt has changed a lot from version 5.2 to 5.9 with respect to resolution, DPI and rendering.

Comment: I've installed Qt 5.8 fresh about half a year ago, and haven't updated to 5.9 yet. I have QT_LIB_PATH=C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin set and the same path in PATH variable. That's it. What else can affect this ?

Comment: Honestly no idea. But you have to think out of the box. The libraries problem is one possible cause. Another possible cause is your display driver. Try to update it? Otherwise I don't know. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, did update of BIOS firmware and display drivers. No change unfortunately. Sigh... :(

Comment: Have you changed any display related settings like text scaling in windows?

Comment: In Krita, I disabled the OpenGL rendering in Display settings, then the problem disappeared. So it is related to OpenGL rendering, some scaling issue.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon, no, the text scaling has always been at 100%.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that in full-screen mode, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has happened after an update of Intel HD Graphics Drivers. Anyway, since I have NVIDIA graphics aswell I tried to force the use of it instead of the default Intel HD Graphics, and voila!, it works perfectly. I had the same problem within Qt Creator, and this solved that as well.

It should be noted that I changed the *default* choice to NVIDIA, and now all applications using Qt work fine.

[image]